# Create trigger that executes maximum one time per day

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table `big_table` with a large number of daily INSERTs, and this table has a column `interesting_val`. For the first row, and first row only, which is inserted after 00:00 UTC on each date, I want to SELECT `interesting_val` and INSERT to another table `daily_interesting_val`. Is this behavior something I can achieve with a combination of procedures and triggers?

Whenever `big_table` has at least one row created after 00:00 UTC, but `daily_interesting_val` does not have a corresponding row with the new `interesting_val`, my application is in an illegal state, and I want to make this time window as small as possible.

One solution I can imagine, but don't if is possible in MySQL:

Create a scheduled procedure that creates a trigger at 00:00 each day. This trigger calls a procedure which (1) checks existence of row, (2) if not exists, insert row, (3) if exists, delete trigger.

Comment: I edited my question a bit. The scheduled procedure is undesirable because I have no way of exactly knowing when `big_table` gets the first INSERT for the day, and I can't tolerate more than a few seconds where my application is in the illegal state.

Comment: To me, the ultimate fix is re-writing the logic of the application. If that logic cannot be completely re-written, a trigger would resolve the issue but you will have performance hits. Is there a duration you'd expect the value to occur? Could you schedule a job to do the check every 30 seconds for the first half hour of the day? That would possibly be a lighter hit than the trigger depending on how many  transactions occur on this table.

Comment: What would be wrong with a `VIEW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INSERT IGNORE` and have a unique key on the date.  The first insert to run for the day will succeed; the rest will be "ignored".

Comment: Do you know anything about what performance hit, if any, I should expect from this?

Comment: @Magnus - "not much".  How often is trigger firing?  How many queries per second are you executing now?    100 qps is easy; much more is possible.  Think of this as adding one more query.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Is this a type of overhead you would deem acceptable if this was a DBMS you were responsible for? You say it's possible with a lot more than 100 qps, but does that mean it's a good idea, or at the very least, *not* a bad idea?

Comment: @Magnus - `INSERT IGNORE` will be faster than `SELECT` + `INSERT`.  It is very reasonable to use it where appropriate.  You seem to be in "premature optimization mode".  Get farther into development.  Then show us a biggeer picture of where performance is _actually_ a problem.

Comment: A million inserts a day, even with a trigger doing the `INSERT IGNORE`, will be easily performed.  A billion a day is a different matter; and the solution won't be found in this lowly `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: Thanks. The material you provide on this Stack Exchange - you as well as other experienced DBAs - is an amazing resource.

Comment: @Magnus - and stackoverflow.com has even more answers!